# Condition on linear combinations of vectors to fill a triangle in 3-d space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have three 3-D vectors  $\vec{a}$,$\vec{b}$,$\vec{c}$, which are linearly independent. Let them start at the origin. If you connect their tips you will get a triangle. Take their linear combinations: 
$$x_1 \vec{a}+x_2\vec{b}+x_3\vec{c}$$ If $x_1+x_2+x_3 =1$ and $x_1\geq0$,$x_2\geq0$,$x_2\geq0$ then you will "fill out" the triangle.

I somehow figured this out by intuition but how to **prove** that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan of an attack:

1. You should first prove that the corresponding thing happens in the plane: Given two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, starting from the origin, the endpoints of the vectors $x_1\vec{u}+x_2\vec{v}$ such that $0\le x_1,0\le x_2,x_1+x_2\le1$, will fill out the triangle. I hope that you are familiar with the result that when $x_1,x_2$ range over $[0,1]$ you get the full parallelogram. Here you are to ID the diagonal.
2. Apply that 2D result to this triangle with the origin moved to the end point of $\vec{a}$, and two suitable difference vectors taking the roles of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

Comment: ok, I understand your reasoning. I am actually sorry that I did not come up with that myself.

Comment: But: The problem did not become so much easier for me. How can I prove that the 2 vectors under the condition fill the triangle and only the triangle? It is so obvious but I don't know how to prove that..

Comment: @user50224: Go down one more dimension! In the 2D-case can you show that the vectors $x_1\vec{u}+x_2\vec{v}$, $0\le x_1,0\le x_2, x_1+x_2=1$ trace the diagonal of the parallelogram with sides $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$? Use the end point of $\vec{u}$ as the "origin", and the diagonal goes along $\vec{v}-\vec{u}$. Then the two halves of the parallelogram come with $x_1+x_2<1$ and $x_1+x_2>1$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is not clear for me yet. 
I have got a real problem with this sort of proof because I don't even know the definitions of the triangle and parallelogram (and geometry..). So, I can't even prove that given a triangle $ABC$ with $\vec{u}$ from $A$ to $B$ and $\vec{v}$ from $A$ to $C$ has $\vec{v}-\vec{u}$ as its 3rd side. What are the axioms, definitions and previously proved theorems I can start with?

Comment: 2nd: Given a triangle $ABC$ with $\vec{u}$ from $A$ to $B$ and $\vec{v}$ from $A$ to $C$. There is a set $S$ of points $(x,y)$ which are all inside the triangle and fill out the whole triangle. How can I prove that the set $T$ which consists of all the points $(x,y)=a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}$ with $a,b$ satisfying the conditions $0 \leq a, 0\leq b, a+b\leq 1$ is equal to the set $S$? I think I would have to show that $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$. How to do that?

Comment: 3rd: (should have been before 2nd): The difficulty for me is that if I make a drawing then everything is obvious about the third side but I read on several occasions that proof by picture is not allowed..
 If I assume $\vec{v}-\vec{u}$ as the third side of the triangle, how can I show that the set $D$ consisting of all points $(x,y)$ on the third side is equal to the set $E$ consisting of all points $(x,y)=a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}$ with the conditions $0 \leq a, 0\leq b, a+b=1$?

Comment: 4th: Actually my problem starts already with the following: 1): Given $2$ points $A$ and $B$ and the vector $\vec{v}$ from $A$ to $B$. Then there is a vector $\vec{A}$ from the origin to $A$ and a vector $\vec{B}$ from the origin to $B$ and thus $\vec{v}=\vec{B}-\vec{A}$. How to justify this?? 2): After having justified 1) how to prove the following?: The set $G$ of points $(x,y)$ of the line segment $AB$ is equal to the set $H$ consisting of all points $(x,y)=x\vec{v}$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$. How to prove this rigorously? What are the definitions, axioms..?